# Deleting the last occurence of a string in a file using java/shell

Tags: java, file, shell, sed

need to delete the last occurence of a string i.e. VirtualHost in a file. I can do it using java, shell.
The file structure is an xml file. What I need is I need to shift the VirtualHost to the end. So I am trying to remove it and then append.

```
 Current Text:
    </VirtualHost>
    #Added for Patch 
    <LocationMatch ^/bea_wls_internal/>
    RewriteOptions inherit
    </LocationMatch>







Desired Text:
#Added for Patch
<LocationMatch ^/bea_wls_internal/>
RewriteOptions inherit
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

i tried to do this:

```
    int c=1,i=1;
    int loc[]=new int[10];
    //String str="</VirtualHost>";
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader (new FileReader ());
    String line=br.readLine();
    FileWriter fw=new FileWriter(file_location);
    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(fw);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    while ((line != null)){
            //System.out.println(line);
            lines.add(line);
            c++;
            line=br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
    int size=lines.size();
    System.out.println("size "+size);

    while(c>i){
        int filesize=lines.size();
        System.out.println(filesize);

        String str=lines.get(filesize-i);
        System.out.println(str);
        lines.remove(filesize-i);
        if (!lines.equals("</VirtualHost>")){
            System.out.println("inside if");
            lines.add(str);
            //break;
        }
        else if(lines.equals("</VirtualHost>")){
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (String writeLine : lines)
            pw.println(writeLine);


    pw.append("</VirtualHost>");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    fw.close();
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

}

Comment: AS of your example, you are doing 2 things, shifting 1 Line and deleting one... Which is it you want ?

Comment: @Rayf plus, he didn't delete the **last** occurrence, but the first `LocationMatch....`

Comment: i need to delete the last occurence of VirtualHost in the file and shift it at the last

Comment: can it be done using sed regex?

Comment: Doesn't look like XML to me. Looks like Apache config

Comment: my bad, yes it is a conf file

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're insisting on using Java?

You could do this with sed:

```
sed '/</VirtualHost>/,$d' filename
```

This will produce the entire file contents minus the `</VirtualHost>`.

Then just include the `</VirtualHost>` in your `#Added for Patch` text.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML parser which can provide the java object. Then traverse from root to desired element and you can perform all manipulation