# Delete the last occurence of a string in a file in unix/linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

Need to shift the last VirtualHost string in a file at eof. I tried using sed

```
#!/bin/bash
tac infile.txt | sed "s/<\/VirtualHost>//; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba" | tac
echo "</VirtualHost>" >>infile.txt
```

Current Text:

```
</VirtualHost>
#Added for Patch 
<LocationMatch ^/bea_wls_internal/>
RewriteEngine ON
</VirtualHost>
RewriteOptions inherit
</LocationMatch>
```

Desired Text:

```
</VirtualHost>
#Added for Patch 
<LocationMatch ^/bea_wls_internal/>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteOptions inherit
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting the last occurence of a string in a file using java/shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19005270/deleting-the-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file-using-java-shell)

Comment: where did `SetHandler weblogic-handler` come from in the desired output?

Comment: there are more than one occurences of </VirtualHost> in my file. I need to remove the last occurence and place it at the end of file

Comment: what's wrong with your command? It seems to do what you want it to.

Comment: the tac statement that i am using is able to print the desired output correctly on the console, but how to do these changes in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command works:

```
#!/bin/bash
tac infile.txt | sed "s/<\/VirtualHost>//; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba" | tac
echo "</VirtualHost>" >>infile.txt
```

And [you comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006421/delete-the-last-occurence-of-a-string-in-a-file-in-unix-linux#comment28080015_19006421) that

> the tac statement that i am using is able to print the desired output
>   correctly on the console, but how to do these changes in the file?

To do so, note the changes I added. They consist in saving the result into a temporary file `new_file` and then moving it to `infile.txt`.

```
#!/bin/bash
tac infile.txt | sed "s/<\/VirtualHost>//; ta ; b ; :a ; N ; ba" | tac > new_file
echo "</VirtualHost>" >> new_file
mv new_file infile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ed` editor comes in handy in situations like these.  It positions itself at the last line of a file when invoked, so all you need to do is search backward for the line you want and delete it.  You can also add back the line just as easily (it makes sense to do that first):

```
echo 'a
</VirutalHost>
.
?</VirtualHost>?
d
wq' | ed -s infile.txt
```

The `-s` option supresses `ed`'s diagnostic output.

**`a`** appends up to a line containing only `.`

**`?`** searches backward

**`d`** deletes a line

**`wq`** writes the file and quits

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '\|^</VirtualHost>|{x;/./p;d};x;/./!{x;b};x;H;$!d;x;s/^([^\n]*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v str="</VirtualHost>" 'NR==FNR {if (index($0,str)) skip=FNR; next} FNR!=skip; END{print str}' file file
</VirtualHost>
#Added for Patch 
<LocationMatch ^/bea_wls_internal/>
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteOptions inherit
</LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

With gawk

```
awk -v RS='/VirtualHost>\n' 'RT{printf prevRT; printf $0; prevRT=RT};
!RT{printf $0prevRT}' file
```